# ansible-playbook host use jinja2

Tags: ansible

ansible-playbook hosts can not use jinja2 for matching more hosts

when i need to install more same service in one host in test env, i write a group like this

```ini
[nginx]
demo-region-nginx-1:22 ansible_ssh_host=10.0.0.1 port=80
demo-region-nginx-2:22 ansible_ssh_host=10.0.0.1 port=81
demo-region-nginx-3:22 ansible_ssh_host=10.0.0.1 port=82
```

my playbook like this

```ini
- hosts: "demo-region-nginx-{{ num }}"
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - role: upgrade_nginx
```

amosttime just setup a "num" when i want to upgrade one nginx, this is easy, if i upgrade nginx-1 and nginx-3, i must be execute multiple times playbook.

In the future, i will have many such service, I must by setup more variable
,so i use jinja2 to filter the hosts, i think jinja2 can fix my problem, but it seems like error, the playbook like this

```ini
- hosts: "{% for num in {{ awx_num }} %}demo-region-nginx-{{ num }}{% endfor %}"
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - role: upgrade_nginx
```

this is error log

```
ERROR! template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {% for num in {{ awx_num }} %}demo-region-nginx-{{ num }}{% endfor %}. expected token ':', got '}'
```

someone know how to fix this error?

Comment: [moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to set variables between brackets inside jinja expression on the for:

```yaml
- hosts: "{% for num in awx_num %}demo-region-nginx-{{ num }}{% endfor %}"
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - role: upgrade_nginx
```

Comment: wow, this is a good answer, it has fix my problem, thank!!!

Comment: If it fits your needing, select is as a correct answer. On the other hand i recommend you to read about Jinja2 expressions and templating. Will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel and making your life complicated. `ansible(-playbook)` has a `limit` option that does exactly what you want.

Given your above inventory and the dummy playbook:

```yaml
- name: Dummy PB to illustrate limit
  hosts: nginx
  gather_facts: false
  
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

Here are some example commands making use of [patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html) for the `limit` argument and their results:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini dummy.yml

PLAY [Dummy PB to illustrate limit] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [demo-region-nginx-1] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-1"
}
ok: [demo-region-nginx-2] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-2"
}
ok: [demo-region-nginx-3] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-3"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
demo-region-nginx-1        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
demo-region-nginx-2        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
demo-region-nginx-3        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini dummy.yml -l demo-region-nginx-1

PLAY [Dummy PB to illustrate limit] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [demo-region-nginx-1] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-1"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
demo-region-nginx-1        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini dummy.yml -l '!demo-region-nginx-1'

PLAY [Dummy PB to illustrate limit] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [demo-region-nginx-2] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-2"
}
ok: [demo-region-nginx-3] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-3"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
demo-region-nginx-2        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
demo-region-nginx-3        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini dummy.yml -l 'nginx[0]'

PLAY [Dummy PB to illustrate limit] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [demo-region-nginx-1] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-1"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
demo-region-nginx-1        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini dummy.yml -l '!nginx[0]'

PLAY [Dummy PB to illustrate limit] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [demo-region-nginx-2] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-2"
}
ok: [demo-region-nginx-3] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-3"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
demo-region-nginx-2        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
demo-region-nginx-3        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini dummy.yml -l 'nginx[1:]'

PLAY [Dummy PB to illustrate limit] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [demo-region-nginx-2] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-2"
}
ok: [demo-region-nginx-3] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-3"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
demo-region-nginx-2        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
demo-region-nginx-3        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini dummy.yml -l '!nginx[1:]'

PLAY [Dummy PB to illustrate limit] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [demo-region-nginx-1] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "demo-region-nginx-1"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
demo-region-nginx-1        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: well, my env may be complex, some time i must be run script on nginx-1,nginx4,nginx10, so i need to a simple solution, just input [1,4,10] or input ['*'] to use all service, thanks you answer

Answer (score 0):

You can put the condition into the inventory plugin [*ansible.builtin.constructed*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html#ansible-builtin-constructed-inventory-uses-jinja2-to-construct-vars-and-groups-based-on-existing-inventory)

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
use_vars_plugins: true
use_extra_vars: true
strict: true
compose:
  awx_num: awx_num
groups:
  hosts_awx_num: "inventory_hostname|split('-')|last|int in awx_num"
```

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts 
demo-region-nginx-1
demo-region-nginx-2
demo-region-nginx-3
```

You can use the list *awx* to select the hosts

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory -e awx_num='[1,3]' --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    hosts_awx_num:
      hosts:
        demo-region-nginx-1:
          awx_num: '[1,3]'
        demo-region-nginx-3:
          awx_num: '[1,3]'
    ungrouped:
      hosts:
        demo-region-nginx-2:
          awx_num: '[1,3]'
```

Use the group *hosts_awx_num* in a playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: hosts_awx_num
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory -e awx_num='[1,3]' pb.yml

PLAY [hosts_awx_num] **************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [demo-region-nginx-1] => 
  inventory_hostname: demo-region-nginx-1
ok: [demo-region-nginx-3] => 
  inventory_hostname: demo-region-nginx-3

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
demo-region-nginx-1        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
demo-region-nginx-3        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Q: ***"Run the play on nginx-1, nginx4, and nginx10, so I need a simple solution, just input [1,4,10] or input ['*'] to use all."***

A: Use the range of the indexes to create the inventory for testing. The two ranges below comprise ten hosts each both with and without the separating dash

```ini
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts
nginx-[1:10]
nginx[1:10]
```

In the configuration of the *constructed* plugin declare default *awx_num|d(range(11))*. All hosts will be included if you don't provide the variable *awx_num*.

In the condition test the pending numbers.

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
use_vars_plugins: true
use_extra_vars: true
strict: true
compose:
  awx_num: awx_num|d(range(11))
groups:
  hosts_awx_num: "inventory_hostname|regex_replace('.*?(\\d+)', '\\g<1>')|int in awx_num"
```

For example,

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory -e awx_num='[1,4,10]' --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    hosts_awx_num:
      hosts:
        nginx-1:
          awx_num: '[1,4,10]'
        nginx-10:
          awx_num: '[1,4,10]'
        nginx-4:
          awx_num: '[1,4,10]'
        nginx1:
          awx_num: '[1,4,10]'
        nginx10:
          awx_num: '[1,4,10]'
        nginx4:
          awx_num: '[1,4,10]'
    ungrouped:
      hosts:
        nginx-2:
          awx_num: '[1,4,10]'
        nginx-3:
    ...
```

Comment: well, that is amazing! I don't even know how this works, let me look at the docs